# Application Server Failed - Service Applications?

Tags: 2013, application-server

My only application server has failed, though I had configured Central Administration with high availability (it's accessible from my web front end server). I tried Googling my problem, though most results were about moving Search Service Application and/or starting with a fresh farm.

My farm currently stands:

- Web applications are on WFEs, so they still load.
- Databases are still live in my SQL servers.
- All SharePoint servers are 2013.
- Service applications won't load - can't search, change managed metadata.
- Application server that failed was called "APP1". New server should, ideally, also be called "APP1".

From what I understand and have read, application servers are scaleable, so my question stands as: In this scenario, to restore access to all of my service applications, should I join a new application server to my farm  using Microsoft's method (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752(v=office.15).aspx), start Central Administration on the new application server, delete the service applications, and provision them again?

Or is there an option to simply start them on the new application server, and SharePoint will tie the knots together as if the app server had never failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

- Install the SharePoint(same version) on new App server
- Join the server to the farm and host CA on it.
- Now from Central Admin > manage Services and start the all required services on few APP server.
- You have to update your [Search topology](http://altfo.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/move-search-components-to-different-server-in-sharepoint-2013/) and if you are using the [UPA Sync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx#moveService) then you have to start that on new server as well.
- after testing, [remove the bad server from farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263130.aspx).

But if you dont have enough data and i would go to delete the service applications and recreate it on new server after joining.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try that. As a side conceptual question, if my farm has a service application, does it reside on a Central Administration web application, or does the CA act just as portal to the service applications (that allows admins access to the service apps) and as long as the service is running on one of the servers on the farm, it will automatically recognize that - say - Search is working on APPSERVER1234 instead of APPSERVER5678 now.

Comment: Central admin is a portal and give you access the services applications. SharePoint is smart enough to recognize the services app if it is running on any server. as i said earlier, you need extra work for UPA & Search..but for MMS simply start on other server solve the issue....One Tip, once you move the services and add new server and remove the old....clear the config cache on all server in farm so that no cached item cause any issue.

Comment: Sorry, last question! When you say "clear config cache", do you mean iisreset? Sorry if that's a newbie question.... I'm trying to learn more along the way, too :)

Comment: this is one i am talking...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx